# Using "WhatsApp" term in Android App Name

Tags: intellectual-property, trademark, branding

I’m trying to create an app name for an Android translator (originally "Translator for WhatsApp") I created that is findable, does not create confusion, and is 30 characters or less per the Playstore restriction.

**Would “Unofficial WhatsApp Translator?” be clear enough to avoid confusion? I could even put disclaimers on all screenshots and descriptions.**

Their brand terms (I'm not using any of their APIs and no formal connection to WhatsApp) say you should not use WhatsApp or any derivative in the name of your product but I'm not sure how I can market a tool for WhatsApp without using the term WhatsApp?

Thanks for your advice.